# C# Wpf Binding type adapter

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

As of now, i assign the image of a TreeView item using a direct binding to the image's source:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:GeoPoint}">
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <Image Source="{Binding Color}" Height="32" />
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
     </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

the Color binding is referring to string containing the path to the PNG, something like "/Resources/red.png"

i would like to make the Color variable of custom type "MarkerColor", an enum containing several colors, and have the image source binding reference this value, so that if

Color = MarkerColor.green; the binding would reference "/Resources/green.png"

Note that the name of the PNG is not necessarily the same as the name of MarkerColor, an "adapter" should be used to convert the type

I know how to do this in Java Android SDK, but not really sure on how to achive this in Wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a converter that knows how to convert the enumeration value to a valid resource:

```
public class ColorResourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        MarkerColor color = (MarkerColor)value;
        Uri uri;
        switch(color)
        {
            case MarkerColor.Green:
                uri = new Uri("Resources/green.png");
                break;
            case MarkerColor.Red:
                uri = new Uri("Resources/red.png");
                break;
            //...
            default:
                uri = new Uri("Resources/default.png");
                break;
        }

        return new BitmapImage(uri);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:GeoPoint}">
    <DataTemplate.Resources>
        <local:ColorResourceConverter x:Key="ColorResourceConverter" />
    </DataTemplate.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="{Binding Color, Converter={StaticResource ColorResourceConverter}}" Height="32" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```